# Question about the intersection of plane variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation for the line of intersection of the planes.

5x - 2y - 2z = 1, 
4x + y + z = 6

So I know  how to solve this equation:

1. Cross the normal vectors
2. Solve for intersection points
3. plug in to equation.

When solving for part 2, I get the following system:

5x - 2y - 2z = 1,

4x + y + z = 6

set z=0

And voila! I get values through solving the system with the z variable removed by z=0.

Question is, why can I set z=0? It doesnt make sense to me.

What other variables can I "make up" to solve these systems of equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiplying your second equation by $2$ and adding to the first we get
$$13x=13$$ thus $$x=1$$ and we get now $$y+z=2$$ and from here we obtain $$y=2-z$$ Setting $$z=t$$ we get the equation of the line as $$x=1,y=2-t,z=t$$ with a real number $t$

Comment: yeah, but why do you set z=t?

Comment: to have a Parameter in your equation you don't need that

Answer (score 0):

Just solve this system:
\begin{cases}
5x - 2y - 2t = 1\\
4x + y + t = 6
\end{cases}
with parameter $t$, or
\begin{cases}
5x - 2y  = 1+ 2t\\
4x + y  = 6-t
\end{cases}
then $$x=\frac{13}{13}=1,\,y=2-t$$
and the line equation is
$$x=1,\,\dfrac{y-2}{-1}=z$$